# How to reduce time in a triple nested for-loop in python

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, for-loop, nested-loops

I want to reduce the time of this triple nested for-loop:

```
dtz = []

for i in range(0, len(Profile)):
    dtz.append(pd.DataFrame(columns=['Strecke', 'Ziel', 'Distanz']))

Columns = ['Strecke', 'Ziel', 'Distanz']
for i in range(0, len(Profile)):
    for col in Columns:
        dtz[i][col] = np.zeros(len(Viertel))

for i in range(0, len(Profile)):
    for j in range(0, len(Fahrstartzeit[i])):
        for k in range(0, len(Viertel)):
            if Viertel[k] >= Fahrstartzeit[i][j] and
                Viertel[k] < Fahrendezeit[i][j]:
                dtz[i]['Strecke'][k-1] = Profile[i]['Strecke'][j]
                dtz[i]['Ziel'][k-1] = Profile[i]['Ziel'][j]
```

The information is this. There are 4.000 'Profile'(For-loop-->`i`), each of this 'Profile' have four(4) columns with different lenght (For-loop-->`j`):  'Fahrstartzeit', 'Fahrendezeit', 'Strecke', 'Ziel'. The vector 'Viertel' (For-loop-->`k`)has intervals of 15 minutes and is this one:

```
Viertel = pd.date_range(start='2012-01-01', end='2012-12-31 23:45:00', freq='15min').to_pydatetime
```

So I want to take into account the departure - 'Fahrstartzeit' and arrival time 'Fahrendezeit'of each trip and write the in the vector 'Viertel'. That means, if a trip starts at 07:13 and ends at 8:35, the information `Profile[i]['Strecke'][j]` in the DataFrame `dtz[i]['Strecke'][k-1]` when the condition is meet. The condition is:

```
if Viertel[k] >= Fahrstartzeit[i][j] and
                    Viertel[k] < Fahrendezeit[i][j]:
```

For example if `Fahrstartzeit[i][j]=02.01.2012 07:02:00` and `Fahrendezeit[i][j]=02.01.2012 08:43:00` it will be written in `Profile[i]['Strecke'][j]=dtz[i]['Strecke'][k-1]` for all `Viertel[k]` that are in between those times:

```
Viertel[k]=02.01.2012 07:15:00
Viertel[k]=02.01.2012 07:30:00
Viertel[k]=02.01.2012 07:45:00
Viertel[k]=02.01.2012 08:00:00
Viertel[k]=02.01.2012 08:15:00
Viertel[k]=02.01.2012 08:30:00
```

Of course this has to be done without much effort, because the vectors are huge.

How can I make this simpler?

Comment: Maybe try code review?

Comment: Avoid recomputing things.  For example, replace every use of `Profile[i]` with `Profile_i`, and add `Profile_i = Profile[i]` just before the `j`-loop.

Comment: If Viertel is sorted then if for some k `Viertel[k] >= Fahrstartzeit[i][j]` then the condition will be truefor all the next Viertels (k+1, k+2...). You can take a similar approach for other comparisons.